# Websphere Process Server 7 utility/script to extract configuration settings

Tags: websphere, websphere-7

I am after a utility or script that can extract useful configuration information about all installed SCA modules and associated applications e.g. Module components (Imports, Exports, Interfaces, Bindings etc), Module Properties, Business Processes, timeout settings, pool sizes etc. Basically all the information viewable using the Integration Solutions Console.

We need this so we can quickly compare settings in our testing, staging and production environments. At the moment we are check settings using ICS and this can take a long time. We are using Websphere Process Server 7 on a UNIX server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Properties-based configuration](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/techjournal/0904_chang/0904_chang.html) utilities to [extract](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/txml_7extractprops.html) all or part of configuration information using . This utility dumps configuration information using the common properties file format, which is human readable and easy to compare. You may use a standard diff tool to compare the properties files extracted from different environments to locate differences.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this out and let you know.

Comment: This is the best we have for the moment. Thanks for your help.